# Why is "attempted relative import beyond top-level package" ValueError, not ImportError?

Tags: python, package, importerror, valueerror, relative-import

When I do a relative import beyond the top level package, I get an exception — no surprise there.  But why is it a `ValueError` and not an `ImportError`?

```
$ find .
.
./b
./b/c.py
./b/__init__.py
./a.py
$ cat a.py
import b.c
$ cat b/c.py
from .. import time_machine
$ python a.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import b.c
  File "/tmp/a/b/c.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .. import time_machine
ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package
```

I would have expected an `ImportError`, because this exception is related to importing packages, and that normally gives `ImportError` (or its subclass `ModuleNotFoundError`).  What is the rationale here?

Comment: I suspect that the rationale is that the _value_ being passed to the import machinery illegal, hence `ValueError`.  If the value was legal but the module unimportable or didn't exist you'd get an `ImportError`.